# Applying CSS property to html in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css like

```css
html {
    zoom: 0.5; /* Old IE only */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

By which the all contents of the browser get smaller to fit with screen size. Now, I want to call a jquery method on resize of browser window and apply the same css properties from there.

How to apply these css props from jquery.

Please note, I need to set the css for **"html"** as shown and not for a div or other html element.

Please advise..

Comment: `$('html').css({ mozTransform : 'scale(0.8)' })` etc.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ what have you tried?

Comment: when you are already having it for `html`, what difference would it make on calling for `resize`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao The value will be determined at runtime and thus required it to call from javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. But as pointed out in comment you should use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Media query should better suit your need.

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "html" ).css({
    "zoom": "0.5", /* Old IE only */
    "-moz-transform": "scale(0.8)",
    "-webkit-transform": "scale(0.8)",
    "transform": "scale(0.5)"
 } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the point? Size of window is not evaluated so will always be the same

Answer (score 2):

you can set a class with the required properties and add that class to html for the required event.

```
.resize {
    zoom: 0.5; /* Old IE only */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    var root = $('html')[0];
    if (!$(root).hasClass('resize')){
        $(root).addClass('resize');
    }
)};
```

Comment: Good solution, but I suspect this keeps on adding `resize` class on `resize`? Also, the OP is saying his values might change on `resize`, so probably wouldn't fit in here..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, thanks for pointing, added a check to add class only once.